# Apache Directory

Tags: java, junit, ldap

I am using [this doc](http://joacim.breiler.com/apacheds/ch05s02.html).

But pom.xml is bit changed (because dependencies from example is not resolved and i have maven error messages), so part of pom.xml i next:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-server-integ</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.client.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>ldap-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then  I am running test from example i am receiving such error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService does not implement the requested interface org.apache.directory.server.core.DirectoryService
at org.apache.directory.server.core.integ.FrameworkRunner.run(FrameworkRunner.java:170)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
```

Any ideas?

Test Class: http://pastebin.com/aPisMRSx

Comment: can you show the class running this?

Comment: Test Class: http://pastebin.com/aPisMRSx

Comment: have you looked at the interface org.apache.directory.server.core.DirectoryService?

Comment: i just copy and past code form example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the version of apacheds-all to the same version as apacheds-core

Comment: Thank you. This error is fixed. Got another, but different exception.