# Apache Directory Tests

Tags: junit, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to run Apache DS for testing

One the my problem is fixed: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859302/apache-directory)

But now am trying to exec [SearchTests](http://joacim.breiler.com/apacheds/ch05s02.html) from this doc

and receive such error: [log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qug9KwES)

Maybe some one have faced with such issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the dependency on shared-ldap-schema if you have it in pom.xml or add an exclusion in pom for this from apacheds-all dependency.

Comment: done http://pastebin.com/print.php?i=dJ6jG4w7, but the same error